# Referencing a parent's value from a child element

Tags: c#, oop

I am trying to figure out a more elegant way to set the property of a parent in c#.  I currently pass the parent into the child element, and reference it that way.  This seems both cumbersome and possibly even incorrect.

The Child:

```
 public class ValidatedField<T>
    {
        public OpenIssues parent { get; set; } 
        //Other values
        public void Highlight()
        {
            parent.isNotValid = true;
            isHighlighted = true;
        }
    }
```

And the Parent:

```
public class OpenIssues
{
    public OpenIssues()
    {
        DateAppealFiled = new ValidatedField<DateTime?>(this);
    }
    public bool isNotValid { get; set; }
    public ValidatedField<DateTime?> DateAppealFiled { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a more streamlined way to reference the parent in this case?  Or am I doomed to sending the entire parent to the child, just to modify one value in the parent?

Comment: there's nothing wrong essentially with a parent call.  That's why it exists.  If you had a telerik grid with a button column and needed the id of the grid from the button, you would need to do something like this:     RadGrid radGrid = (RadGrid)((ImageButton)source).Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent;
         This is the kind of stuff you run into when you have multiple grids that share common classes.  Yes it looks retarded, but it's the easiest way to do it.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but from the names of your classes I would suppose that the `ValidatedField` should perform some sort of validation on some data - and that validation would be called from the `OpenIssues` class. If that's the case, why not have the validation method simply return a `bool`  and set the `isNotValid` of the `OpenIssues` class as the result of the validation method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a more streamlined way to reference the parent in this case?
>   Or am I doomed to sending the entire parent to the child, just to
>   modify one value in the parent?

The entire parent (in your words) is just a few bytes of reference/pointer

However,

You can essentially do this one of 3 ways

1. Pass in a concrete reference or interface from your parent.
2. Use events/delegate/action and register then trigger them on update
3. Or a decoupled pub/sub messaging system or mediator

What you are doing is fine, though all have their downsides and are cumbersome in different ways

The most modern approach is a decoupled messaging system, this is common in viewmodels where you don't want to couple view models and classes together. However, this is most likely overkill for trivial situations.

Also too, actions and events have their places as well. The parent(or someone) subscribes, and unsubscribes (well... should).

However, if you don't mind the tight coupling of your parent and child, and if there is little need to use them in different parent child configuration, just use references. No harm done.

Comment: I don't suppose I could request code examples for each.  Seeing them side by side might help us narrow down which is least/most cumbersome!  I will mark correct answer from there.